# Regex - Match every comma NOT between delimiters

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

> This seems to be a frequent kind of question here on StackOverflow,
> but I couldn't get it working properly. Apologies for any inconvenience.

I need to split a string for every comma found outside of a group delimited by pairs of dollar signs. I'm using Javascript.

Expected behavior: `"$g=9,8m/s$, p,q, $m=19,0$, banana"`

Should return `["$g=9,8m/s$", "p", "q", "$m=19,0$", "banana"]`

---

Ideally, dollar signs prefixed by `\` should be ignored as follows:

`"$$g=9,8m/s$$, p,q, $price=\$19,0$, banana"`

Returns `["$$g=9,8m/s$$", "p", "q", "$price=\$19,0$", "banana"]`

But for now I'm happy without this feature.

---

My best attempt was `(\$[^\$]*\$)|[^,]+`

Which matches just the first group, returning: `["$g=9,8m/s$", "p", "q", "$m=19", "0$, "banana"]`

What am I getting wrong here? Appreciate your help!

Comment: `s.match(/\$+[^$\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^$\\]*)*\$+|[^,\s][^,]*/g)`? See https://regex101.com/r/NeHzPs/1

Comment: Yes perfect! Thank you Wiktor. I've just noticed that the spaces between each comma were problematic. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s.match(/\$+[^$\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^$\\]*)*\$+|[^,\s][^,]*/g)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NeHzPs/1)

**Details**

- `\$+[^$\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^$\\]*)*\$+` - one or more `$` chars followed with any 0 or more chars other than `$` and `\`, followed with 0 or more repetitions of a `\` and then any single char and then 0 or more chars other than `\` and `$`, and then 1 or more `$`s
- `|` - or
- `[^,\s][^,]*` - any char other than comma and whitespace and then any 0 or more chars other than a comma.

Comment: Hello, Wiktor! Sorry to bother you again with this regex, but I have found a small problem in situations when a comma is immediately followed by a dollar sign group. `Hello, $I'm$ Willy` should result in `["Hello", "$I'm$ Willy"]`, but currently it returns `["Hello", "$I'm$", "Willy"]`. [Here is a regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NeHzPs/2) with some failing examples. Could you help me with this one?

Comment: @N.H.Deutschland Try `s.match(/(?:\$+[^$\\]*(?:\\[\s\S][^$\\]*)*\$+|[^,])+/g)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/NeHzPs/3).

Comment: It works perfectly, thank you! If anyone finds this thread, just add `.map(s => s.trim())` after `s.match()` to trim eventual spaces placed after each comma.